# How to get ASP.NET Identity authentication ticket expiry in Razor Page?

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, razor-pages

I'm using identityserver4 with ASP.NET Identity, with a cookie configured with SlidingExpiration = true and ExpireTimeSpan = 20 minutes. I would like to provide the user with a warning when they are about to timeout so am trying to access the ".expiry" value in the cookie.

So far I have been able to read *an* expiry time using the Razor code below. **However** this is failing to read the correct expiry time when the user refreshes their ticket. According to the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.2) SlidingExpiration should provide my user with a new ticket if they refresh the page 10 minutes or more (>= 50% of ExpireTimeSpan) after getting a ticket. It does this fine, but when it does so the code below provides the old expiry time until the user refreshes the page for a second time!

```
@(DateTime.Parse(((await Context.AuthenticateAsync()).Properties.Items)[".expires"]))
```

What I want to know is how do I get the correct expiry time on the page generated when the new ticket is provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've kind of solved my issue, **I don't much like this solution as it's quite hacky**. It does work though so I'm posting it here in case it is helpful. I'd much appreciate it if anyone can help me understand a better solution, I'll edit this answer or delete it in favour of another if/when that happens.

I get the authentication ticket expiry in much the same way as in my question, then if there is less than 50% of my ExpireTimeSpan setting left I assume it would have renewed (a bit risky maybe but so far it's the best I've managed). I use this to calculate the assumed number of seconds remaining until timeout, then use this value when deciding when to show the user a warning.

At the top of the Razor (partial):

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
```

The important bit of my code (feel free to suggest improvements):

```
secondsRemaining = "@(DateTime.Parse(((await AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions
                                             .AuthenticateAsync(Context))
                                             .Properties
                                             .Items)[".expires"])
                     .Subtract(DateTime.Now)
                     .TotalSeconds)";
// If secondsRemaining is less than half the expiry timespan then assume it will be re-issued
if (secondsRemaining < timeoutSeconds / 2) {
    secondsRemaining = timeoutSeconds;
}
```

Comment: along these lines but somewhat cleaner may be a combination of middleware that fires after the cookie middleware that sets up a variable in HttpContext.Items and then an MVC filter that pops that into ViewBag which can then be accessed in your views.

Comment: I had a good look for a way to do that (other than by forking the MS code per your other suggestion). I found no way to get at the correct value for the ticket expiry at any place in the pipeline other than on a subsequent page load. On reflection, my solution doesn't achieve that either so I could just use the AuthenticateAsync line from above, with the subsequent assumption about refresh and stick that in HttpContext.Items for use in the idle timeout partial. It's still hacky but at least it wouldn't be trying to mess around with the response body.

Comment: I realised there's no need for messing with the response body, or even for using HttpContext.Items; I've edited my razor view as per my edited answer above. It's a bit hacky because it just assumes that the ticket was renewed (though that's probably a fairly safe assumption) but it works. Thanks again for your help @mackie

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the renewal is happening after your page is rendered - the new properties will only be available on subsequent requests.

An option may be to use client side code to poll for the latest expiry time but this would have the effect of being a keep-alive which is possibly not what you'd want.

To mitigate the above you could create your own cookie middleware implementation (all the source code is on github) and customize the sliding expiration logic (CheckForRefresh and RequestRefresh). You may also be able to add the new expiry time to the HttpContext and thus make it available to your controller code earlier.

Source code: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies

You only need to create your own version of CookieAuthenticationHandler (less than 500 lines of code) and your own registration helper (check out CookieExtensions):

```
public static AuthenticationBuilder AddCustomCookie(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, string authenticationScheme, string displayName, Action<CookieAuthenticationOptions> configureOptions)
{
    builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IPostConfigureOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, PostConfigureCookieAuthenticationOptions>());
    return builder.AddScheme<CookieAuthenticationOptions, CustomCookieAuthenticationHandler>(authenticationScheme, displayName, configureOptions);
}
```

Comment: Thanks mackie. It had crossed my mind that the expire time wasn't being set until after the page renders and I had the idea of writing some temporary custom middleware to help identify exactly when the expire time is being set.

I'm contemplating writing some middleware that will just update the expire time. Either in the cookie if I can before rendering the page, or otherwise in the rendered page after the cookie expiry is set. It has a bit of a hacky feel to it but I think it should do the job. I might see how that goes before deciding if it's worth the effort of your approach. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm currently having a go at your approach but falling at some very early hurdles. If I create my own CookieAuthenticationHandler how will I tell Asp.NET Identity to use my CookieAuthenticationHandler? Also I'm looking at the code for CookieExtensions.cs and have little clue as to how to use it to create my own registration helper or what to do with that registration helper once it's created.

Comment: @Rob Basically you'd create you own extension method like `AddRobCookie(...)` and change the `AddScheme...` call to take `RobCookieAuthenticationHandler` instead of `CookieAuthenticationHandler`. In your `Startup` class you'd use your new extension method.

Comment: @Rob Added an example

Comment: Thanks @mackie I'd got that far since my last comment, but don't understand how to tell Asp.NET Identity to use my CookieAuthenticationHandler.

Comment: You can register you custom scheme with the default name and it should work exactly the same way as the standard cookie middleware

Comment: Sorry @mackie I guess your hints would be enough for a more experienced Core developer but I'm unable to get enough from them to know what to do. The failure might well be all mine, but I don't know what you're suggesting I do. Are you suggesting I copy all the code from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies and then edit CookieAuthenticationHandler and CookieExtensions? How can I "register [my] custom scheme" to enable Asp.NET Identity to use it? Thanks, Rob

Comment: @Rob yes, more or less, although it's only the CookieAuthenticationHandler that needs replacing, all the other supporting types remain the same. One you have the registration helper in place you can call AddCustomCookie(...) in your Startup class replacing the existing call to AddCookie(...). This will register the handler against whichever scheme name you specify and the authentication internals of ASP.Net will then use your handler whenever that scheme is invoked. Once that's in place you can tweak the code in your handler to support your use-case.

Comment: thanks again for your help but this solution seems like a lot of work for the sake of supporting a user friendly idle timeout. Forking .net framework code doesn't strike me as particularly future proof and I imagine it to be a source of more pain further down the line, I don't think it's worth that risk in this case. Thanks, Rob.

Comment: @Rob You're not wrong, I only really suggested it since I'd already had to do similar but for a completely different reason. See my comment on your solution - I think there's a way to avoid having to rewrite the content like that.